# How can I make the sign out option to not appear even though I already pressed 1 to sign in (do while loop Java)

Tags: java

Hello I am currently new to Java and I would like to know how can I make the sign out option disappear since I already entered the option to sign in.
TL;DR the sign out option is still appearing even though I already pressed 1 to sign in.
I also need help on making a deduction and salary system 
Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Security{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    BufferedReader dataIn=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int sign=0;
    int hour=0;
    int minute=0;
    int out=0;
    int hour2=0;
    int minute2=0;
    int pre=0;
    int late=0;
    int deduction=0;
    String Str_1;
    String Str_2;
    String Str_3;
    String Str_4;
    String Str_5;
    String Str_6;
    String Str_7;
    try{
        System.out.println("Press 1 to sign in ");
        Str_1=dataIn.readLine();
        sign=Integer.parseInt(Str_1);
        System.out.println("Press 2 to sign out ");
        Str_5=dataIn.readLine();
        sign=Integer.parseInt(Str_5);
        if(late>=3)
        {
            System.out.println("Your Salary has been deducted");
            deduction=pre-50;
        }
        do{
           System.out.println("Everytime you sign in you get a 50$ salary");
            System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
            Str_2=dataIn.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Hour: ");
            Str_3=dataIn.readLine();
            hour=Integer.parseInt(Str_3);
            System.out.println("Enter Minute: ");
            Str_4=dataIn.readLine();
            minute=Integer.parseInt(Str_4);
            do{
                System.out.println("Number of lates: "+late);
                late++;
            }while(hour>7||minute>30);
            if(hour<=7&&minute<=30)
            {
                System.out.println("You are on time!");
            }
            else if(hour>7||minute>30)
            {
                System.out.println("You are late!");
            }
            System.out.println("Press 1 to sign in ");
            Str_1=dataIn.readLine();
            sign=Integer.parseInt(Str_1);
            System.out.println("Press 2 to sign out ");
            Str_5=dataIn.readLine();
            sign=Integer.parseInt(Str_5);
            }while(sign==1);
           while(sign==2)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter Your Name: ");
            Str_5=dataIn.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Hour: ");
            Str_6=dataIn.readLine();
            hour2=Integer.parseInt(Str_6);
            System.out.println("Enter Minute: ");
            Str_7=dataIn.readLine();
            minute2=Integer.parseInt(Str_7);
            System.out.println("Thank you for working hard!");
            System.out.println("Here's your salary!");
            pre=0+50;
        }
        System.out.println("Press 1 to sign in ");
        Str_1=dataIn.readLine();
        sign=Integer.parseInt(Str_1);
        System.out.println("Press 2 to sign out ");
        Str_5=dataIn.readLine();
        sign=Integer.parseInt(Str_5);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Oops you entered something wrong");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you elaborate with sample output what you exactly want?

Comment: Even though I already pressed 1 to sign in the sign out thing will still appear. https://imgur.com/a/3HTaf

Comment: Edit: I found the fix from Er.Er but If I press 2 it would still redirect me to the sign in form rather than the sign out one. And also it will never stop unless you input a wrong value (Letter on an integer)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Press 1 to sign in , Press 2 to sign out ");
Str_1=dataIn.readLine();
sign=Integer.parseInt(Str_1);
if(sign==2)
  Str_5=Str_1;//i write here because maybe u need str_5
```

But why are you using str_1,2,3,4,5...

```
sign = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked but I have another problem! If I press 2 it would still redirect me to the sign in form rather than the sign out one

Comment: And also it will never stop unless you input a wrong value (Letter on an integer)

Comment: you need to be more specific when redirect you to sing in . Do you change everywhere and do you debug this code before ask ?

Comment: What I mean is when I press 2 to sign out it would still go to the sign in thing but this only occurs in the 1st input where you press 1 or 2 to sign out, and yes I tried debugging it by changing the while loop to do while and tried removing the if (sign==2).

Comment: Oh and it will also prompt the "press 1 to sign in, 2 to sign out" 2 times and after that it will only prompt the sign out form which is the second loop the one where it will say "thank you for working hard here's your salary"

Comment: because first doing and after controlling. you need to try directly while not do-while

Comment: Thank you for the response I'm gonna redo all my code and consider your advice!